# Добавление рисунка в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, xaml, bitmap

Есть такое задание: пользователь выбирает папку, из которой нужно просмотреть картинки. Эти картинки добавляются в ЛистБокс. Я знаю, как из папки считать картинки в List, но я не знаю, как динамически добавить картинки в ListItem. Подскажите варианты, пожалуйста!

Код XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <MenuItem Header="Open" Width="50" Click="MenuItem_Click" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
    </Menu>
    <ListBox Name="ListBox1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow">            
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Код C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    IList<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();        

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();            

        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath))
            {
                images.Add(new Bitmap(file));

                // ListBox1.Items.Add() // не знаю, как добавить Image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ListBox1.ItemsSource = images; Только вне цикла

Comment: В папке у меня были 2 картинки формата jpg.
В ЛистБокс добавились надписи:
System.Drawing.Bitmap
System.Drawing.Bitmap

Какие внести изменения в XAML или C# код, чтобы отображались картинки в Листбоксе ?

Answer (score 1):

Изменение первое:

```
IList<System.Windows.Controls.Image> images = new List<System.Windows.Controls.Image>();
```

Изменение второе:

```
private List<string> filter = new List<string>() { @"bmp", @"jpg", @"gif", @"png" };
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
       System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

       if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
       {
           foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath))
            {
                if (filter.Exists(n => n == file.Split(new char[] { '.' }).Last().ToLower()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file));
                        var img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                        img.Source = bi;
                        images.Add(img);
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                     }                        
                }
            }
            ListBox1.ItemsSource = images;
        }
}
```

Подходит пожалуй только как пример, правильным будет, написание модели которая выдает на ваши запросы ObcervableCollection, а всю необходимую обработку хранит внутри.

Comment: Большое спасибо !!!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, ещё, как прописать фильтр здесь.
Знаю, как прописывать для OpenFileDialog, а здесь такой подход не получается (

Comment: @Владимир, подправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Давайте сразу делать правильно, а не городить сложную логику в code-behind. А значит, используем [паттерн MVVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel).

Объявляем вью-модель `MainModel` со списком файлов `Files` (для простоты просто коллекция строк с полными путями). Из вью `MainWindow` вызываем загрузку, то есть банальное перечисление файлов в директории.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Files { get; private set; }

        public MainModel ()
        {
            Files = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        public void LoadFiles ()
        {
            var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                Files.Clear();
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath))
                    Files.Add(file);
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var model = new MainModel();
            DataContext = model;
            model.LoadFiles();
        }
    }
}
```

(Можно сделать более чисто, но пока не будем фокусироваться на командах и прочем. Это "грязный MVVM", но для простых приложений его достаточно.)

Вью тогда становится проще некуда:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

WPF сам позаботится о том, чтобы загрузить картинки и отобразить их при пролистывании. В качестве бонуса за счёт виртуализации вы будете иметь ленивую загрузку картинок.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста. А как можно с помощью Слайдера увеличивать или уменьшать картинку в ЛистБоксАйтеме, которые загрузились динамически ? Возможно так сделать ?

Comment: @Владимир Можно. При помощи `{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}`. Но если у вас возникают подобные вопросы, стоит начать с прочтения толстой книжки.